# Python: retrieve objects's value from a class object

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Here is my problem, I'm creating a Tkinter GUI
and in a class object I call for a text tipped in a textfield and make an array of it

But I can't find how to retrieve and use this object later on in the script.

Here my script

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from pylab import *
from ttk import *
import ScrolledText

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 500, size = (10, 20)), index = list('abcdefghij'))
    mylist = df.index.values.tolist()

    rootWin = Tkinter.Tk()
    class GraphGUI():
        def __init__(self, rootWin):
            self.textfield = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(rootWin, width=30, height=10)
            #Add some text:
            self.textfield.insert(INSERT, "Replace")
            self.textfield.grid(column=0, row=4)

            self.button = Button(rootWin, text="Process!", command=self.clicked)
            self.button.grid(column=1, row=4)


        def clicked(self):
            eText = self.textfield.get('1.0', END)
            converted = eText.encode('ascii','ignore')
            myarray = converted.splitlines()
            print(myarray)


    def clicked2():
        print(clicked.myarray)

    start = Tkinter.Button(rootWin, text="start!", command=clicked2).grid(column=7, row=8)

    app = GraphGUI( rootWin )
    rootWin.mainloop()
```

The problem is when I click on the process Button no problem myarray get printed.
But when I use the start button I can't retrieve it.
Is there a way to retrieve myarray out of the Class object?
Also Is it possible to print myarray with the Start button without having to use the Process button first?

##### EDIT

Here the final working script thanks to the help

```
class GraphGUI():
    def __init__(self, rootWin):
        self.textfield = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(rootWin, width=30, height=10)
        #Add some text:
        self.textfield.insert(INSERT, "Replace by your Accession list")
        self.textfield.grid(column=6, row=4)

        self.button = Button(rootWin, text="Process!", command=self.clicked)
        self.button.grid(column=7, row=4)

    @property
    def myarray(self):
        e_Text = self.textfield.get('1.0', END)
        converted = e_Text.encode('ascii','ignore')
        return converted.splitlines()

    def clicked(self):
        print(self.myarray)
        print(variablea.get())    #not defined here#
        print(variableb.get())

def clicked2():
    print(app.myarray)

start = Tkinter.Button(rootWin, text="start!", command=clicked2).grid(column=7, row=10)
```

Comment: This code doesn't run.  Can you edit in the rest of the code to make this runnable?

Comment: Sorry i didn't add the imports
It is edited now

Comment: Your indentation seems like it's screwed up. Can you fix it please?

Comment: And as an aside -- please try to avoid `from modulename import *`. It leads to some INCREDIBLY polluted namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to access a local variable of an object method. That's not possible. If you need it, try defining it as its own callback instead.

```
class GraphGUI():

    def __init__(self, rootWin):
        self.textfield = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(rootWin,
                                                   width=30,
                                                   height=10)
        # Add some text:
        self.textfield.insert(INSERT, "Replace")
        self.textfield.grid(column=0, row=4)

        self.button = Button(rootWin, text="Process!", command=self.clicked)
        self.button.grid(column=1, row=4)

    def clicked(self):
        eText = self.textfield.get('1.0', END)
        converted = eText.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        myarray = converted.splitlines()
        return myarray

rootWin = Tkinter.Tk()

app = GraphGUI(rootWin)
start = Tkinter.Button(rootWin, text="start!", command=app.clicked)
start.grid(column=7, row=8)  # your code assigned `start = None` btw
rootWin.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, `myarray` could just be defined as a property of the class.

```
class GraphGUI():
    ...

    @property
    def myarray(self):
        e_txt = self.textfield.get('1.0', END)
        converted = e_txt.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        return converted.splitlines()

    def clicked(self):
        print(self.myarray)
        # do whatever else it has to do


rootWin = Tkinter.Tk()
start = Tkinter.Button(rootWin, text="Start!",
                       command=lambda: app.myarray)
...
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for as Process will do also other things than just printing myarray.
That's why i'm looking how to create another button that will only call myarray
So apparently there is no other way to retrieve myarray for something than adding the whole piece of script that is processing myarray in GrapgGUI?

Comment: @Jérémz if `GraphGUI.clicked` returns `myarray`, then you can access it with `app.clicked` no matter what else it does. Alternatively you can define `myarray` as a property of the class. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam it did the trick for me even if I had to change a little thing to make the button work (see in edit)
Though I don't really get how @property is working can I add as many property for a class as I want and are they all independent?

Comment: @Jérémz properties are just functions that act like attributes. If you didn't have the `@property` decorator, you'd have to access it with `app.myarray()` instead of `app.myarray`. Since that looks like an attribute to me, I called it a property.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a local variable in the method of an object, which you simply cannot do.

What you *can* do is that that other method *return* the object, or you can convert that local variable into an instance variable.

The simplest solution is to have the function return the data that you want:

```
class GraphGUI():
    ...
    def clicked(self):
        ...
        return myarray

def clicked2():
    myarray = app.clicked()
    print("myarray:", myarray)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan your method is working on me but give multiple time the array return. see in the edit for the method that give the best result on me